# Нужна ли запятая перед «несмотря на»?

Tags: пунктуация

В июне в журнале «Nature Communication» появилась статья о том, что были найдены перья детёныша динозавра, отлично сохранившиеся несмотря на 99 миллионов лет, проведённых в янтаре.

Comment: всё же перед "несмотря" обязательно нужна запятая. наверно %)

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_482 вот

Comment: я конечно дурашка, просто решил поделиться личными исследованиями :) возможно я не прав.

Comment: Интересно, мать какого ныне существующего вида нужна, чтобы вырастить динозавра из ДНК?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В июне в журнале «Nature Communication» появилась статья о том, что были найдены перья детёныша динозавра, **отлично сохранившиеся несмотря на 99 миллионов лет, проведённых в янтаре.**

**Розенталь** [§94. Обособленные обстоятельства](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm#%D0%B7_03)

Как правило, обособляется оборот с предложным сочетанием несмотря на, например: Каждую летнюю зорю Герасим, несмотря на слепоту, ходил в поле ловить перепелов (Бунин). **Но при тесной смысловой связи со словом, после которого находится этот оборот, не обособляется и он, например: Пришел администратор, вызванный несмотря на  поздний час.**

Здесь как раз **тесная связь оборота с причастием**, нет паузы и запятой.

Вообще говоря, обособление в таких случаях должно зависеть от структуры предложения, **но часто решение делается формально (без учета замечания Розенталя о тесной связи с определяемым словом).** Так, в приведенных ниже примерах обособление **обозначено в обоих случаях**, но в первом предложении пауза явно отсутствует, а во втором случае она факультативна.

(1) Тонкие черты, **сохранившиеся несмотря на ожирение лица,** с первого взгляда приводили на память портрет знаменитого композитора Россини;  [Д. В. Григорович. Литературные воспоминания (1893)]

(2) Обращали на себя внимание также и его удивительно молодые, аристократически тонкие, необыкновенно чуткие и подвижные, будто у юноши, пальцы рук, **чудно сохранившиеся, несмотря на его почтенный возраст** (Антон Висков. 2004.06.15).

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения логики, это предложение не вполне корректно. Нахождение в янтаре способствует сохранению растительных и животных остатков, поэтому не сочетается с "несмотря на". Фактически перья сохранились несмотря на их древность благодаря тому, что находились в янтаре. Исходя из этого, мой ответ (который, возможно, примирит сторонников и противников постановки запятой [smile]): употребление предлога "несмотря на" в данном случае неуместно, предложение должно быть перестроено. Как вариант:

**В июне в журнале «Nature Communication» появилась статья о том, что были найдены перья детёныша динозавра, отлично сохранившиеся после 99 миллионов лет, проведённых в янтаре.**

Answer (score 0):

**[НЕСМОТРЯ НА (что), *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_482)**

> Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «несмотря на», обычно обособляются
>   (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого
>   или тесно связан с ним по смыслу).

В Вашем предложении "несмотря на" - предлог, ср.:

*Он сделал это несмотря на запреты врачей* -

оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу *(сделал несмотря на запреты)*.

---

У Розенталя, см.:

[**Обособляются, как правило, обороты с предлогом *несмотря на* и невзирая на**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm).