# Надо ли обособить оборот с "несмотря на..." в конце фразы?

Tags: пунктуация

> Ангела Меркель выбрала Владимира Путина, несмотря на угрозы Дональда Трампа.

Нужна ли запятая?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Не смотря на последствия" или "несмотря на последствия"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424991/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1):

**Ангела Меркель выбрала Владимира Путина, несмотря на угрозы Дональда Трампа.**

Нет здесь факультатива, **запятая ставится по основному правилу.** В примере по ссылке рассматривается другая конструкция (уступительный оборот внутри  обособленного причастного оборота).

**О тесной связи**

Тесная связь со сказуемым и ее достаточность определяется не видением автора, а **смыслом, грамматикой и структурой** предложения.

Например: **Он вышел из дома несмотря на запрет врачей**.

Оборот находится в конце предложения и не обособляется.
Но здесь оборот  **входит в основное сообщение,** так как содержание первой части не является самодостаточным.

Речь идет не о том,что он вышел из дома и куда-то пошел, но о том, что он нарушил запрет (это содержание второй части простого предложения).

(В этом случае пауза не подчеркивается, а только обозначает естественный перелом интонации).

*Ангела Меркель выбрала Владимира Путина* – это предложение самодостаточно, а оборот *несмотря на угрозы Дональда Трампа*  по содержанию и грамматике соответствует **придаточному уступительному предложению.**  Интонация также соответствующая, то есть пауза ясно обозначена.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте здесь: [rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432367/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-несмотря-на](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432367/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Краткий вывод такой: оборот, начинающийся со слов «несмотря на», достаточно тесно связан с предшествующим сказуемым и может запятыми не выделяться. Пожалуй, это уже случай факультативного употребления, на усмотрение автора.